# Eclipse src folder empty

Tags: eclipse

So for my class I need to use eclipse to do some graphics stuff in Java. I've tried both Eclipse standard 4.4 and Eclipse for Java developers, but with both when I tried to create a new Java project, the src folder is completely empty. Why is that?

Edit: I should add in more information. In the lab section of my class I was able to follow the instructions and create a lab 1 project src folder, which contains many files such as Lab1.java, Polygon1.java and all that. When I am trying to do it on my own machine, it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's a blank canvas!!

Right click on the src file New->Class

Give the new class a name and a package and you're away, you can start coding.

If you want to include libraries create a new lib folder at the same level as the src folder and copy any jar folders into this folder.  Right click on the .jar files and click Bukd Path->Add to Build path, you'll now be able to import and classes contained in this jar file(s)!!!

Comment: i've added more information, please let me know if it's still unclear!

Comment: Right click is your friend!  Right click the src folder and you will find what you are looking for!!

Answer (score 0):

Because you created a new project. If you haven't added any code yet, why would there be code in the src folder?

Comment: i've added more information, please let me know if it's still unclear!

Comment: Well, when you create a new project in Eclipse, it isn't going to be creating a bunch of java files for you. Eclipse doesn't know anything about your class and doesn't have collections of course-specific files pre-loaded. You probably copied a folder in your class rather than actually creating everything from scratch. You probably need to talk to the TA/Teacher about this.